# AS3: How would I detect negative numbers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In my AS3 application, I am trying to make my value set to 0 if it goes into the negatives, this is because if someone clicks something too many times, it can go into the negatives. I want to make this impossible.

This is my code below, however, it *thinks the negative numbers are above zero.*

I've tried a variety of different code and a variety of online searches to no avail.

```
if(this.getData(2) > 0)
{
    this.setRes(2,0);
}
```

I am wanting it so that if the value is negative, it gets set to 0. Currently, it sets it to 0 whenever it is lower then zero, however, that doesn't work above. If I set it to use a < larger then symbol, it proceeds to lock at 0, even though it is a negative number I set it to start as for testing purposes.

How would I make it detect negative numbers so it knows the difference? Or better yet, just solve this issue?

Comment: Normally it's a simple **if (something < 0)**.

Comment: @Organis It doesn't set the value to 0 though, it seems to mistake a negative number for being larger then 0, as if it never was negative or something. Is there an alternative way to do it?

Comment: Well, you should probably post a verifiable example, so that **if (-1 < 0)** is **false** instead of **true**.

Comment: @Organis I guess I will give up here, since the variable is manually set to -50, and in that if statement, if it is lower then 0, a negative number will read higher in value. I'll just instead focus on working on my cooldown question unless someone here appears to have a possible solution.

Comment: @Organis is right to the point as usual but can You pease describe the data type used for your values?
I just post a sample as an answer for more readability

Comment: @tatactic My value is a uint. Is that why it won't go into negatives? How can I make it? Should I just change it to int, will it work without changing anything else?

Comment: AMO yes @Blake Xavier

Comment: let me know if this solve Your issue... @Blake Xavier

Comment: If Someone downvote the question please let us know why. THX.
Otherwise @BlakeXavier will not understand how he must improve his question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the the data type of your numeric values uint, int, Number???
Did You checked if the real value is really a negative value?

```
var a : uint=1;
var b : int=1;

trace ("( a : uint = " + a + " ) - 1 = " + ((--a) as uint));
trace ("( a : uint = " + a + " ) - 1 = " + ((--a) as uint));
trace ("a : uint (" + a + ") < 0 ? -> " + (a < 0)); // !!! return false
trace ("( b : int = " + b + " ) - 1 = " + ((--b) as int));
trace ("( b : int = " + b + " ) - 1 = " + ((--b) as int));
trace ("b int (" + b + ") < 0 ? -> " + (b < 0)); // !!! return true
```

Output :

```
( a : uint = 1 ) - 1 = 0
( a : uint = 0 ) - 1 = null
a : uint (4294967295) < 0 ? -> false
( b : int = 1 ) - 1 = 0
( b : int = 0 ) - 1 = -1
b int (-1) < 0 ? -> true
```

Comment: @Blake Xavier can you just tell us what kind of data type are specified for your values???

Comment: uint , that seems to be it, isn't it?